# Using a condition with an event

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is the code I want to implement. Simply stated, it is a small chat bot that connects to a server and joins room `testroom1` with credentials `user` and `pass`. Using a library, an event is called every time somebody enters a message into the chatroom, and this bot will print their message, with formatting:

```
import ch

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
  for x in range(0, 3):
    def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
      print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))

rooms = ["testroom1"]
username = "user"
password = "pass"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

However, the key problem is this:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
```

I only want the "onMessage" function to be accessed 3 times then to not print any more messages. This doesn't seem to work, and it continues to print messages until I exit it.

If possible, I would like to limit the onMessage function with while loops further in my program, and to use it in several different cases to parse messages at different times.

The source of the ch library and basis for my simple code is [here](https://sinister.ly/Thread-Tutorial-Chatango-Bot-Tutorial)

Any insight on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the code for the base class `ch.RoomManager` or where ever else `easy_start` is defined? Also  is it possible that you intended to put your for loop inside the method `onMessage`?

Comment: The code is too long, so I pasted RoomManager here: https://pastebin.com/aJzYbFhc

As is, or without the loop, the onMessage method runs continuously. I would like to use onMessage to print messages during the last few seconds of a countdown, and then using it again in a completely separate case to process the messages for commands.

Comment: This is the full ch.py where onMessage can be found: https://pastebin.com/8ukS4VR1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the Python syntax slightly. The for loop in your class will define the same `onMessage`method three times, with each new iteration replacing the old one. This would be apparent if you tried to use the `x` (or rather `self.x`) within your function.

What you want, is a counter within the method or class, that is incremented with each call and then, when the max count is reached you could just have the `onMessage`method do nothing.

Try the following code, which I think does what you want:

```
import ch

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
  messages_left = 3

  def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
    if self.messages_left > 0:
      print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))
      self.messages_left -=1 

rooms = ["testroom1"]
username = "user"
password = "pass"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

What I have done here, is to add an initializing function that defines an object variable `messages_left` that is decremented in the `onMessage`call, until it hits zero. Further, I have added a class parameter, which allows you to control how many times you want onMessage to format the message.

Comment: Thank you, this code is working now. I have further questions on making this a bit more complex, using time as a determinant in the loop. Should I ask as a comment here?

Comment: It is probably a better option to ask a new question, since that will more likely attract more attention and improve your chances of getting an answer. Also, it will probably help if you improve your reputation (and karma ;-)) by up-voting and accepting this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467515/loop-within-a-class-negates-the-code-before-it this is the new question that I have asked. Thank you again for your help with this one!