# loop within a class negates the code before it

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In a previous question, the issue was how to implement a conditional loop (a simple for loop) to affect the onMessage event calling function, which was resolved. However, my current issue is in trying to implement time as the determinant in the conditional loop.

Currently, the code runs but only seems to do the while loop that rechecks the time, ignoring the code before it. I suspect that the issue is in the location that I have placed the time rechecking loop?

Any clarity on this issue would be appreciated!

```
import ch
import time

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
    timeleft = 0
    starttime = 0

    def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
        print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))
        if 100 >= timeleft >= 1:
            print('success')
        else:
            print('fail')

    loop = 1
    while loop == 1 :
        timeleft = starttime - int(time.clock())
        if timeleft <=0:
            timeleft = 200
            starttime = 200

rooms = ["testgroup444"]
username = "user"
password = "name"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

For clarity on the methods used, the entire ch.py library can be found here: https://pastebin.com/8ukS4VR1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and rephrase your question

Comment: What do you mean by "the code before it"? the method `onMessage`? it never been called

Comment: bot.easy_start runs the code. If you remove the loop, and time conditions, you will see that onMessage will run,

Comment: BTW, `int(time.clock())` is always `0` (at least on unix)

Comment: Testing int(time.clock()) in powershell says otherwise. It is initially 0 since it counts from the first time it is called. Afterwards, it starts returning the seconds passed in int

Comment: I think it is better to use `time.time()`, rather than `time.clock()`which gives the time in seconds since "epoch". Also, please clarify what you expect the code to do. Should  `onMessage` print 'success' for 100 seconds, then print 'fail'?

Comment: Yes, I think using time.time() would be better. I mistakenly forgot to add starttime = 200 at the bottom. timeleft should begin at 0, get set to 200, then start counting down. The program should print fail for the first 100 seconds, then print success, then repeat as timeleft reaches 0 and gets reset to 200. The issue is that onMessage doesn't occur at all, as if the code only contained the while loop and nothing else.

Comment: When should time = 0 happen? Directly after the call to `bot.easy_start` or at the first call to `onMessage`? Or should you perhaps listen to another event to set time to zero? As soon as the use case is better understood, it will be easier pointing you in the correct direction.

Comment: Technically, time=0 should occur as early as possible, as it will be later changed to 200. Eventually, I would like that value to be a variable, such that I can change "timeleft" depending on other factors, but yes, it should always begin at 0 as early as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still have an issue with the Python syntax. In Python whitespace is very important as it defines scope. The way your code is written, the while loop is executed at the time the class is defined, before anything is started.

Further, the code gets into an infinite loop, as `while loop == 1` will be always `True`. This is why you see that your code gets stuck. From the discussion in the comments, I imagine you want to write something like:

```
import ch
import time
import enum

class State(enum.Enum):
    idle = 0
    nominating = 1
    voting = 2
    watching = 3

class bot(ch.RoomManager):

    state = State.idle
    movie_length = 20

    def updateState(self):

        if self.state in [State.idle, State.nominating]:
            self.state = State.voting
            timeout = 10
        elif self.state == voting:
            self.state = State.watching
            timeout = self.movie_length - 15
        else: # if self.state == watching
            self.state = State.nominating
            timeout = 15

        self.setTimeout(timeout*60, bot.updateState, self)

    def onConnect(self, room):
        # Redirect through event loop, not strictly nessecary
        self.setTimeout(0, bot.updateState, self)

    def onMessage(self, room, user, message):

        print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))
        print("Current state is {0}".format(self.state))

rooms = ["testgroup444"]
username = "user"
password = "name"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

Here, the `setTimeout` method defined in the ch (bot) class is used, to allow messages to be passed at certain times. At every timeout the state is updated. The actual state is then available in all internal methods, e.g. in `onMessage` and `updateState`.

As I do not use the chat network or client I cannot guarantee that the solution works, though.

Comment: Well, I wrote the loop in mind such that other operations could be done that use current time as well, without having to depend if someone posts a message or not. Thus, I require the loop to be infinite, so that the time is always counting down, then resetting. 

This is the reason why I had the time loop separate, to have it as a center-point to have other functions' operations, like onMessage, dependent on the current time's calculation, and not vice versa.

Comment: I see, but you still do not want an infinite loop in your class definition, as that will make your program get stuck there, and never do anything else. If you want, to access the time from more places, make it a method, for example as in my updated code.

Comment: My idea is to also open a file as soon as the timeleft reaches 0, as well as some other operations, without any delay. Would that be possible with this code as it is?

Comment: No, that is not possible with this solution. That is somewhat more complicated, as it requires that you get notified when time reaches zero. Here the time is checked when `onMessage` is called. I haven't checked the chatbot framework you are using, but maybe it provides a way to setup timers?

Comment: I don't think so. ch.py is essentially a rudimentary API with the Chatango website that a user created. For further clarity, I'll explain the full program that i have in mind.

Comment: The program starts at time 0. This sets it into vote mode. An intermission video is played and timeleft changes to 10 minutes (the length of the intermission) the intermission serves to vote on a movie to play. As none have been nominated, all candidates are simply chosen randomly. Users vote on movies using !vote (movie). When the timeleft reaches 0 (the intermission ends), the voting system also ends, and the movie is played.

Comment: Timeleft is changed to the length of the movie, and the program do nothing until timeleft reaches 15 minutes before starting nomination mode, wherein users can nominate movies that will be used as candidates in vote mode, when timeleft reaches 0 again. So, timelength will follow a cycle of 0->10:00->0->(movielength)->0->10:00 and so forth. Each 10 minute section being the intermission voting section, and the movielength being the movie being played, with the nominations occuring in the last 15 minutes. As you can see, everything is dependent on time, and is occurring live

Comment: Currently, the only thing this question is trying to solve is the way this real time "function" can be implemented as a center point. I realize the syntax is wrong as is, but I have no other idea on how it could work. Possibly as an event?

Comment: I checked the library and there is an `setTimeout` method in the class. This is able to help you with the things you are interested in. I might have a chance to draft a solution in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thank you, I'll also look into it further, though I believe you would reach a better solution

Comment: OK, I have added my last edit to this question. Hopefully you can make something out of this. There is quite a bit of theory needed to understand this, having to do with event loops to handle asynchronous events. And, as I wrote in my answer, I cannot test the code, so there are probably some errors that you need to iron out. But, if it is helpful, please up-vote and accept the answer.

Comment: I think I understand this correctly, and I believe this is the solution I am looking for, but it will take time for me to test it. I may have further questions in the future, would you mind if I could contact you in such a case?

Comment: JohanL, how would I be able to start the event loop without going through onConnect? Specifically, to prevent skipping the loop should the bot disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what you want to do, but if you look at the source code for ch.py, you see that there are a number of `onXyz()` methods. You could use these to have things happen at different events. Perhaps you want to start the timer from `onInit()` rather than from `onConnect()`? That way it will be called only once, when the bot is first started. Or maybe you want some magic to happen in `onReconnect()`?

Comment: No no, I think onInit() would work. Yeah, I simply don't want the event loop to accidentally be called again after it starts. If I understand this correct, would this syntax be correct (replacing def onConnect)?:


    def onInit(self, room):
        self.setTimeout(0, bot.updateState, self)

Comment: Except, the `onInit()` call does not take any `room` parameter, so it would be only `def onInit(self): ...`.

Comment: Thanks again, this seems to work a lot better! Would it be possible to make the program check if it's connected, and reconnect if not? I've tried using onDisconnect event, but it seems to only be triggered if the program itself calls disconnect(), and not when the connection is involuntarily lost. Also, after the initial connection succeeds, the program doesn't inherently know whether it's still connected or not. If I turn off the connected after it starts, it will continue the loop as if nothing has changed.

Comment: Hey! I think I got the reconnection problem working. I created a small function to ping chatango.com every few seconds and check if it succeeded. If not, a variable called "connectedstate" would become false, and so the next time the function would make a successful ping, it would use bot.stop(self), then restart the bot using the same bot.easy_start. Then, sing a simple bool variable with onInit, I made sure that the loop is only started once, and the command is ignored if the bot should ever need to be restarted.